# How can I organise my unit tests to run in a particular order in Python Nosetests

Tags: python, nose

I have a set of 50 odd unit tests scheduled to be run/executed using Python Nose-tests.

These 50+ unit tests are written in an order and such that, they leverage the output of the previous one, when run as one test suite.

However, Nose-tests seems to pick a order of its own and doesn't really care for the order I've configured the unit tests.

I've looked around for possible answers/references on stack overflow, but without success. Can anyone point me to any existing configuration parameters or Nose-tests Flags that can be set, to have the unit tests within the test suite to be executed in a given order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two answers,

- unittests should be written in such a way that you don't need the outcome of the previous test to be able to continue running the other tests... that's the whole idea about abstracting the "units" that you're testing. If you really want a scenario test then write it as one test.
- as stated by [jeberle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867757/jeberle%20%22jeberle) test are run alphabetically. if you really want you can

`def test_01_foo():
    assert foo()
def test_02_bar():
    assert bar()`

Comment: Thank you. This helps. I had to actually number my tests in the Incremental order.

Answer (score 0):

**Nose** runs the tests in a specific order:

> Like py.test, nose runs functional tests in the order in which they
>   appear in the module file. TestCase-derived tests and other test
>   classes are run in alphabetical order.

More here: [nose.readthedocs.io](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html)